# How to interact with a smart card in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, smartcard, apdu, pcsc

Is there any open framework written in C/C++ which helps in interacting with smart card devices, here my aim is to create such a system which is platform independent by in C/C++.

I have been trying to search such Libraries but all i came across is Java based frameworks like OCF and Java Smart Card I/O API.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Though StackOverflow is not a recommendations engine, the very tags you used may suggest a combination search to see what kind of options people are using.  Try for instance [the combination of smartcard and c++ tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartcard%20c%2b%2b) search.  Looking at the activity can suggest popularity, and looking at the kinds of issues people are having can be evidence of usability or breadth of features.  Notice the feature is done by putting multiple tags in brackets in search **[c++] [smartcard]** and you can use other terms too.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there are methods like [SCardEstablishContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SCardConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379473(v=vs.85).aspx), [SCardTransmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you use to establish communication with the smart card, and then send commands to the card, on the APDU level.
See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/SC)

Comment: How about for the cryptographic needs? For example, to setup the secure channel.

Comment: @eigenfield Hi, this is old post. I've not played with smart cards and C++ since.